# How to make Fragment conformation for listening Delegate events of Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I've a Fragment which start new activity with `Intend` like:

```
Intent intent = MyActivity.getIntent(getContext());                
startActivity(intent);
```

In `MyActivity` class I have created interface:

```
public interface MyActivitySelectedListener {
   void onButtonSelected();
}
```

and added setter which will be responsible for setting delegate:

```
public void setMyActivitySelectedListener(MyActivitySelectedListener listener) {
    this.mMyActivitySelectedListener = listener;
}
```

So I have create Delegate pattern, but here is an issue. How to make Fragment to be responsible for handling `MyActivitySelectedListener` events in my case?

I can't access to `setMyActivitySelectedListener` method from `Intend` class. Maybe there is another how to do that in right way? I will appreciate if you will point me right direction.

Comment: You can access the delegate inside a fragment by 
    ((MyActivity)getActivity()). setMyActivitySelectedListener()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the delegate inside a fragment by

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).setMyActivitySelectedListener()
```